# Assigning type to parameter from imported library in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am struggling with declaring the right type to a function parameter i use and i don't seem to understand the logic behind it please help.

The following situation:

```
const { U64 } = require("somepackage");

export const someFunct = function (
    someParameter: any ( this is of type U64 ) 
){...}
```

If i replace any with U64 i get:

```
'U64' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof U64'?
```

If i use someParameter: `typeof U64` the parameter still says any if i hove over it.

What am i missing? How is this supposed to be done?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA3jAqgNgCwwL4wLwwE4CmAjgK4CWhAFAERhrUCUA3AFAsEAeADiHrKJFgQQAWwIAxEmGBQy4HDABmUmXLAxKwsQAUAhnl1ioBPAC4kaBvBYwYA4QBsCAOgcgA5ptEE9BoyeYWDBYAehCYMkUYAE8QEhgACxAANxMYFLSoBIIYLn1DAmM8CKFZBwcYCCSAdwgYXTBo9m5efnBoerAQLJNJaVl5XGV+tQ0tH3z-MxgoaK4CECiUVCtzWfnFi1Q4Gzt2kCdXDy8dScKA1ltCKBI8dXHfAqLWYJZxvtVwSmXKAAYOACMACYAMyoACsyAA7AAOACcv1+DAYoXCkRicUSGWK2Jm2SUKgG6jIpTI5UqNTqDSaDW62TwHyJ3zQf0BoIh0PhiORQA)

Comment: What does `U64` look like? Or what package is exporting `U64`? Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because as your question stands, there is not enough information to answer it. You can use something like [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to allow others inspect types easily.

Comment: `typeof U64` should work. If it still shows as `any`, maybe the type of `U64` is actually inferred to be `any` for some reason?

Comment: Maybe this package doesn't export types

Comment: Thank you for the comments i added a Typescript Playground to illustrate the problem. it is this package: https://github.com/chjj/n64

Comment: @DarjuschSchrand: thanks for adding a reproducible example with the package name. The package you're using doesn't export types so TypeScript is unable to type it hence the resolved type is `any`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, that means there is no solution and i just leave it as any?

Comment: You could author your own types, see documention on [TS declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).